# SQL Query to Move Rows to Columns in a table, plus aliases

Tags: sql, sybase, rows, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get data from one database and put it in the format of a second database, where the schemas are different.  I'm trying to get data that is in multiple rows of one table into a single row, with some logic to change the field names.   I will have a unique ID (encounterID), which will be a key in the result table, and is a foreign key in the multiple rows.

Here is my desired output schema, a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpSurgery
(       
EncounterID INT NULL,
RvAmplitude DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvImpedance DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvPulseWidth DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvVoltage DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvCurrent DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
LvAmplitude DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
LvImpedance DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
LvPulseWidth DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
LvVoltage DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
LvCurrent DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvLvAmplitude DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvLvImpedance DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvLvPulseWidth DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvLvVoltage DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
RvLvCurrent DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
AtrialAmplitude DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
AtrialImpedance DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
AtrialPulseWidth DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
AtrialVoltage DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
AtrialCurrent DECIMAL(7,2) NULL
)
```

Notice that there are fields with prefixes Rv-, Lv-, RvLv- and Atrial- for Amplitude, PulseWidth, Impedance, Voltage, and Current in different columns.   My Source table #tmpLeads has the following columns:

```
LeadID
EncounterID
LeadValue
Amplitude
PulseWidth
Impedance
Voltage
Current
```

Where LeadValue is in ('Rv', 'Lv', 'RvLv', 'Atrial') and EncounterID is the same, and LeadID is the unique key for each row in the field, and doesn't need to be in the result table.

In my case, there will usually only be two rows in #tmpLeads for each EncounterID, but the LeadValues could be any two of the distinct LeadValues above (never two 'Lv's, two 'Rv's, or 'RvLv's, etc, but an 'Lv' and an 'Atrial', or an 'Atrial' and an 'RvLv'.)

So, finally, my questions:

How do I select the values out of #tmpLeads to update #tmpSurgery, so that I update the appropriate values based on LeadValue, so I have one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO #tmpSurgery 
(
    EncounterID,
    RvAmplitude,
    RvImpedance,
    RvPulseWidth,
    RvVoltage,
    RvCurrent,
    LvAmplitude,
    LvImpedance,
    LvPulseWidth,
    LvVoltage,
    LvCurrent,
    RvLvAmplitude,
    RvLvImpedance,
    RvLvPulseWidth,
    RvLvVoltage,
    RvLvCurrent,
    AtrialAmplitude,
    AtrialImpedance,
    AtrialPulseWidth,
    AtrialVoltage,
    AtrialCurrent
)

SELECT 
    tblDistinct.EncounterID,
    tblRv.Amplitude,
    tblRv.Impedance,
    tblRv.PulseWidth,
    tblRv.Voltage,
    tblRv.[Current],
    tblLv.Amplitude,
    tblLv.Impedance,
    tblLv.PulseWidth,
    tblLv.Voltage,
    tblLv.[Current],
    tblRvLv.Amplitude,
    tblRvLv.Impedance,
    tblRvLv.PulseWidth,
    tblRvLv.Voltage,
    tblRvLv.[Current],
    tblAtrial.Amplitude,
    tblAtrial.Impedance,
    tblAtrial.PulseWidth,
    tblAtrial.Voltage,
    tblAtrial.[Current]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EncounterID FROM #tmpLeads) as tblDistinct
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpLeads as tblRv 
    ON tblRv.EncounterID = tblDistinct.EncounterID
    AND tblRv.LeadValue = 'Rv'
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpLeads as tblLv 
    ON tblLv.EncounterID = tblDistinct.EncounterID
    AND tblLv.LeadValue = 'Lv'
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpLeads as tblRvLv 
    ON tblRvLv.EncounterID = tblDistinct.EncounterID
    AND tblRvLv.LeadValue = 'RvLv'
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpLeads as tblAtrial 
    ON tblAtrial.EncounterID = tblDistinct.EncounterID
    AND tblAtrial.LeadValue = 'Atrial'
```

Check it out in action [here on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119851/).

Comment: Thanks so much, and thanks for introducing me to the DataExplorer.  Cool stuff.